# Change the default 'naming scheme' for copying files

Tags: windows, file-transfer

When I copy a file, `name.txt`, in Windows Explorer and paste in the same directory, a new file appears.  Its default name is `name - Copy.txt`.

Is there a way to customize the default name for a new file which is a copy.
For example, I'd like to have the copy be `name_12345678.txt` where `12345678` is a timestamp. Is it possible to achieve this using Windows' configuration and not with any 3rd party software?

Comment: I remember that in XP it was possible to change some settings 'rather close to what you are asking', like the menu when right clicking, by editing configuration files. Newer Windows seem much more restrictive. It would surprise it what you are asking is possible in newer Windows versions.

Comment: @OlofEdler: I don't recall **any version** of Windows allowing such functionality by merely editing configuration files, including all the way back to Windows 3.1.

Comment: You are dead wrong on this one though friend. I am absolutely positive that I could _change a file in 'the folder above my home folder'_ in win XP. Which resulted in me, _when right clicking_, having other menu options. Was pretty cool. A COULD CHECK THIS UP, how it was possible, but thinking I have better things to do. Felt kind of hacky for a young kid, felt good. Was totally sad when vista came out. Have not used windows regularely for years tough (which says nothing).

Comment: I think it was the one. Almost positive. **Create a new file** (from right clicking). You could add a lot of other things. File types I guess. No. I did not experiment with it much. Found it in a forum. Tried it. It worked. MAGIC! Feeling pleasue of knowing something others did not know.

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned a non-third party solution, but you might be able to approximate a first party solution by using a program, such as TeraCopy or SuperCopier, that hook into explorer, and "take over" the copy/cut/paste operations.  These programs are highly customizable, and the developers are readily amenable to suggestions for improvement if they don't already have the features you are looking for.